# Cross-platform C++ 2D game engine with actual object orientation

Tags: c++, game-engine

I'm looking for a cross-platform (Windows, Linux, Mac) C++ 2D game engine with an actual object oriented approach, instead of just crappy singletons and such. I'm looking to create some small, physics-based, free and open source games, so the license must be either MIT/BSD or GPL.

I found many good options, but they were all in high level languages and the development seemed stalled. LibGosu, for example, seems great, but it lacks basic stuff like collision detection. LOVE, Cocos2D are great, but they're in Lua and Python, respectively. Is there any good C++ alternative that does not make my life a dependency hell and allows me to write proper OO code?

Comment: why do you consider "actual object orientation" a good approach to making games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/)

It's easy to use, and there are many physics engine you can add to it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a tradeoff between having a prebuilt object model ready to go and rolling your own. While it may be faster to start with a prebuilt OM, it might not suit your needs later down the track, and will be a pain to modify (or more likely *work around*) to your needs. This is why a lot of engines expose their functionality at a slightly lower level then you might code your client against, requiring you to create the "glue" layer yourself.

As for finding an engine, **you can just use a 3D engine** with quads/sprites and an orthogonal projection on your camera (which is just constricted to move through a plane) to get the same effect as a 2D engine. You can basically fix the Z component of your 3D (say to `0`) and you can treat it more or less like 2D. Plus you will likely get a more performant engine with the added benefit of being able to easily incorporate 3D features and concepts later down the line if you want to.

You will have a much wider variety and likelihood of finding what you need (from an API/OM sense) than if you restrict yourself to 2D engines.

Answer (score 2):

Check out cocos2d-x, a c++ port of cocos2d-iphone. Combined with Box2D ( http://box2d.org/ ) for simple physics, it offers a lot of possibilities.

Both are c++, under MIT and zlib license respectively.

Edit: as of cocos2d-x v2, the linux port is no longer supported ( http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Tutorials )

Comment: Cocos2d-x has no Linux support, as far as i am aware.

Comment: I never tried it myself on Linux, but according to their wiki, it seems to be supported: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki

Comment: "But please note that linux port is only exist on cocos2d-x v1.x versions, we remove this port in v2.0". It sucks, sadly. :(

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [ClanLib](http://clanlib.org/wiki/Main_Page)?

I used it to create a small 2D game myself. Linux and Windows are supported (Mac only partially, however) and it is C++. Also, it has many basic features and optional graphics card acceleration and such. The license is very liberal.

Comment: Yes, i did, but quite unstable on Mac OSX and the code is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

COCOS2D-x is OK for you, but it doesn't include collision detection, so you need to realize it  by yourself or use third-party lib. I recommend [Box2d](http://box2d.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Angel2d](http://angel2d.com/) is an object orientated game engine for develop fast prototypes for games in the developmet phase. Since it is programmed in C++, later on you can use the code for the real development phase too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Oxygine](http://oxygine.org/) game framework. It is based on top of SDL2